# Create class, struct, or new swift file to create reusable text boxes with a certain style?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm new to swift, and... well, programming all together. I've been at it for a few weeks but only started learning swift yesterday. 
I'm trying to build an app that's like a different version of truth or dare, and you press a button and it randomly picks one for you and gives you the truth or dare along with it.

I want to use a `text` box with some design to it, to look basically like a card, for truth, and for dare. I was thinking I could some how use an `@State var` with a list of these items and have it randomly display one. I'm going to have another card in there but it won't be as common as the truth and dares.

I'm just not sure if I should use a `struct`, `class` or `swift` file to create these so that I can reuse them, as the `list` would contain more than one of each, as to create more rarity for the other mystery one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's normally, when you don't know how to begin. As I understand you mean "what do I need to create?". First of all I'll suggest, that you definitely need to create new `.swift` file. 
Also I suggest you to try just separate your `View` and some logic. So your class or struct will just "give some data" and your `View` will just present this data. 
For more information about "do you need use classes or structs" please read [this Apple's article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes). Shortly: choose structures by default.
But remember: here almost nobody will write the full code in your place and community does not like such kind of questions.

I also advice you to go through [Apple SwiftUI tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/) to realize how you can organize the application. I hope it'll help you to start.

Answer (score 0):

you can create own custom text box view

or you can create modifier to apply to the needed textboxes

both ways is correct

```
import SwiftUI

//Create own view - Custom Text Box
@available(OSX 10.15, *)
public extension View {
    func CustomTextBox( ) -> some View
    {
         Text()
             .AnyModifier1()
             .AnyModifier2()
             .AnyModifier3()
             .modifier( CustomModifier() ) // <- applying custom modifier
    }
}

//Create custom modifier
@available(OSX 10.15, *)
public struct CustomModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State var checker: Bool = false

    public init() { }

    public func body (content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack{
            content
                .AnyModifier1()
                .AnyModifier2()
                .AnyModifier3()
        }
    }
}
```